# findViewById on a ViewPager returns 'Android.view.View', cannot be cast to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

## [SOLVED]

I'm trying to follow [this turorial](https://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/) to get a ViewPager on my Wearable application. However, when I try to assign the ViewPager in my XML to a variable, it only recognises it as a "View", and not as a ViewPager. This gives me the error below:

[image: Error]

When checking other tutorials, none of them seem to have this issue. They can all easily assign their ViewPager to their variable...

**viewpager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ViewPager.java**

```
/*
*
* VIEWPAGER TUTORIAL
* https://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/
* door the pseudocoder
* */
public class ViewPager extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
      * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
      */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
        //initialsie the pager
        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the fragments to be paged
     */
    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Monitor.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, CurrentSongOverviewWear.class.getName()));
        this.pagerAdapter  = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
        pager.setAdapter(this.pagerAdapter);
    }

}
```

It is this line in initialisePaging() that gives me the error:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
```

Comment: post your imports thanks.

Comment: Deadcode's answer already fixed it, but thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you named your class `ViewPager`, it now tries to cast a view to your type of `ViewPager` which extends from `FragmentActivity`. This is, of course, not a `View`.

Renaming your class - to `ViewPagerActivity` for example - will fix your issue. If you look at the code of that tutorial, you'll see that they used `ViewPagerFragmentActivity`

Comment: Oh my god..... What a dumb mistake to waste a day on.... thanks a lot! I'll verify your answer when stackoverflow allows me to!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you imported **`android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`**
2. Change **Activity** name .**[ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)**  Itself a Class. Must Rename this .

**Example**

```
 public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

Comment: @LievenLuyckx change Actvity name

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your Activity to another name, for instance : ViewPagerActivity

or cast the view to right format :

```
android.support.v4.view.ViewPagerpager = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
```